# VBA On Error GoTo suddenly stopped working

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, runtime-error

I have an issue with the error handling in VBA.
The code has previously worked, but now suddenly errors are not handled by `On Error GoTo` statements and instead the code is crashing and giving a pop up with the error message as if `On Error GoTo 0` would be active.

Here is an example of how the code structure is:

```
On Error GoTo logError

For d = 0 To Doclist.Count -1
    On Error GoTo DownloadFailed
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[30]").press
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub:SAPLSPO4:0300/ctxtSVALD-VALUE[0,21]").Text = filepath
    On Error GoTo logError
    ...

DownloadFailed:
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo logError
Next d

logError:
    ws1.Cells(1, 7).Value = Err.Description
    Workbooks("Main.xlsm").Save
```

In the first iteration the `On Error GoTo DownloadFailed` is working as expected, but after this the code is crashing.
The error that I am getting is Run-time error '619'.
I saw on some similar post to clear the error with `Err.Clear` but this did nothing to my code.

In another part of the code I am using `On Error Resume Next` which at the same time stopped working.
As mentioned the code has worked previously so I have no idea what could be wrong.

Does anybody have experience with similar issues and any possible solutions for this?

Comment: Check the VBA Editor debug settings to make sure the option *'Break on all errors'* is not turned on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Error Trapping is set to Break on Unhandled Errors.

Comment: The main issue is that the "happy path" and the "error path" are intertwined. Never cross the streams!!

Comment: See the reasoning behind Rubberduck's [unhandled OERN](https://test.rubberduckvba.com/FeatureDetails?name=UnhandledOnErrorResumeNext) inspection for tips on correctly handling errors inline.

Answer (score 2):

### Error Handling

- The `GoTo` keyword is kind of reserved for the error-handling routine so this solution is strict about that.
- Some contributors argue though that it is OK to use the `GoTo` keyword to skip a code block in a loop but I don't think it refers to doing it with `On Error`.

```vb
Sub ErrorTest()
    
    Dim LogErrorFound As Boolean
    Dim ErrNum As Long
    On Error GoTo LogError ' start error-handling routine
    
    For d = 0 To Doclist.Count - 1
        On Error Resume Next ' defer error trapping
            session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[30]").press
            ErrNum = Err.Number
            If ErrNum = 0 Then
                session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub:SAPLSPO4:0300/ctxtSVALD-VALUE[0,21]").Text = filepath
                ErrNum = Err.Number
            End If
        On Error GoTo LogError ' resume error-handling routine; clears error
        If ErrNum = 0 Then
            '...
        
        'Else ' download failed i.e. 'ErrNum <> 0'; do nothing!?
        End If
    Next d

ProcExit:
    
    If LogErrorFound Then
        On Error Resume Next  ' defer error trapping; avoid endless loop
            ws1.Cells(1, 7).Value = Err.Description
            Workbooks("Main.xlsm").Save
        On Error GoTo 0 ' stop error trapping
        MsgBox "A log error occurred.", vbCritical
    Else
        MsgBox "Finished successfully.", vbInformation
    End If
    
    Exit Sub

LogError: ' continuation of the error-handling routine
    LogErrorFound = True
    Resume ProcExit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

While `Err.Clear` does clear the error object, it does not re-enable error handling like `Resume` or `On Error GoTo 0`. In order to manually do this, replace `Err.Clear` with `On Error GoTo -1` like this:

```vb
On Error GoTo logError

For d = 0 To Doclist.Count -1
    On Error GoTo DownloadFailed
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[30]").press
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub:SAPLSPO4:0300/ctxtSVALD-VALUE[0,21]").Text = filepath
    On Error GoTo logError
    ...

DownloadFailed:
    On Error GoTo -1
    On Error GoTo logError
Next d

logError:
    ws1.Cells(1, 7).Value = Err.Description
    Workbooks("Main.xlsm").Save
```